# What happens if I use status on a Magic Bounce with a Magic Bounce pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

So let's say I have a Mega Absol vs Xatu or something. Both have Magic Bounce. What would happen if Mega Absol used Will-o-wisp?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mega Absol would be affected by it and receive a burn. If both pokemon have Magic Bounce, it will only reflect the move once- causing the user to be hit.

Source: [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Magic_Bounce)- If two opposing Pokémon have this Ability only the target's Magic Bounce will reflect the move (i.e. the move will only be reflected once).

Comment: Do note that Will-o-wisp's accuracy is still taken into effect when Magic Bounced - so it has a chance to miss the user